# Avoiding multindex read in read_csv

Tags: csv, delimiter, multi-index

I'm trying to read a csv, that appears to have a problem in a specific line.

I'm trying to explore the problem, since I got the error

```
Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 23 fields in line 27, saw 37
```

Here's what I discovered:

the first 26 lines are read OK:

```
zero=pd.read_csv(basepath/nome, low_memory=False, dtype=str, delimiter=";", nrows=25)
```

but at line 26, the function takes a multindex dataframe, even if the database doesn't have multindex.

```
zero=pd.read_csv(basepath/nome, low_memory=False, dtype=str, delimiter=";", skiprows=25)
```

Even forcing the index to None (index_col=None), the result is a multindex table (the table is shown with the first 9 cols of indexes)...

how can I avoid this and read the csv properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 23 fields in line 27, saw 37
```

Most likely there are separators inside some fields in that row.

Make sure those fields are quoted and `quotechar='"'`.

---

To handle quotes contained in a field like:

```
"L.E.P. DI PIROZZI CARMINE S.A.S.\"";;;;;;;; "08020650019";
```

`escapechar='\\'` can be used.

Comment: Actually, the quotechar argument doesn't solve the problem: i realized that a field in that db contains two following quoting marks (' " ', opening the csv in a text file it appears it appears like this: "L.E.P. DI PIROZZI CARMINE S.A.S.\"";;;;;;;;
"08020650019";)
This makes impossible to the csv_reader to detect the delimiters!
I'm wondering how to address this problem...

Comment: @f.g.fornari In this example the quotes inside a field are escaped with a '\' (Linux style). Sometimes those quotes are escaped with another quote (which would have given S.A.S."""; instead. This can probably be solved by using escapechar = '\\'.